# MongoDB update paradigm

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Trying to get my hands dirty with MongoDB, coming from a relational database background.

I believe one of the main concepts of MongoDB is to keep as much data together as possible.

Imagine I create an application that have products and categories, and I store products this way:

**Products collection**

```
{
    "_id": "30671", //main item ID
    "department": "Shoes",
    "category": "Shoes/Women/Pumps",
    "brand": "Calvin Klein",
    "thumbnail": "http://cdn.../pump.jpg",
    "title": "Evening Platform Pumps",
    "description": "Perfect for a casual night out or a formal event.",
    "style": "Designer",
    …
}
```

**Categories collection**

```
{
    "_id": "12356",
    "name": "Shoes"
    …
}
```

If I update a category name, would I need to run a huge update command to update all products as well? Or in this scenario it would be better to actually store the category ids against the products instead of their names (like we would do on a relational database)?

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as "NoSQL". It's just a collective term. You either use MongoDB or Firebase or Cassandra or whatever. Typically in RDBMS land everything speaks the same SQL. When dealing with the others there is **no common language**. So you can stop referring to things by "NoSQL" because it actually does not mean anything. Only the syntax of the desired target system is all that matters.

Comment: Next Point. Whist you **can** store data in multiple collections, the thing you should be asking is *"Do I really **need** to?"*. When the answer is **NO**, then that's when you start looking at the "non-relational" based database solutions. When it is **YES**, relational models are better, unless of course there is a significant part of the domain logic that would be better suited to the other engine, and using different engines is out of the question. So the bottom line is your "question here" is way too broad. It's not about **what's best**, but rather about **what's best for you**.

Comment: @NeilLunn, I described my question using a trivial example (cats/prods). Same concept could easily be applied in other situations. So it's not a matter of what's best for me, I'd like to hear from somebody more experienced with MongoDB what to do in these cases where you have the same information in multiple places. I thought that was what Stackoverflow was about, sharing knowledge.

Comment: The problem here it *"It's far **too trivial**"* and not a good enough representation of what you want to do. And it **IS** only about **what is best for your application** and the "specific" pattern it needs to use. There is no such thing as **Best Practice** here, which is all your question appears to be asking. So what I am telling you is **too broad** and in order to get anything useful it **must** be completely about a "specific" use case. Which this is not. Understand now? Or perhaps you might want to click on my username here and work out if I'm "experienced" enough for you.

Comment: @AndreFeijo if you update the category name then yes you would need to run an update statement on the products table you can use `updateMany()` to accomplish this.  `Should we store category Id in product collection` - this is dependant on your application / size, as Neil has mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general there is no "one-size-fits-all" approach in MongoDB like it is in relational database world. In a relational schema design, it is a no-brainer to put `Category` in a separate table. In fact, it is almost a requirement to do so during normalization process.

In MongoDB, schema design almost entirely depends on what you need and your use case more than any rule-of-thumb or any formulated requirements. Of course, there are pluses/minuses for each choice. For example:

- If you find in your use case that `Category` doesn't change much (or at all), then you can safely put it inside the `Products` collection. However, should you need to rename a category, then yes you would need to update all the products belonging to that category.
- If you find that your use case requires flexibility in changing category names, then you may want to put it into a separate collection and refer to it like in a relational design. However, returning a product may not be as performant since now you need two queries instead of one (or a lookup).

I noticed that you used `"category": "Shoes/Women/Pumps"` in your example. In MongoDB, you can put that into an array if your use case allows it, e.g. `"category": ["Shoes", "Women", "Pumps"]`. This *may* make the field easier to index (again, depending on your use case).

In short, there is no right or wrong in MongoDB schema design with one caveat: usually the wrong thing to do is trying to emulate a relational design in MongoDB, since it goes against the grain.

You also may find these links helpful:

- [6 Rules of Thumb for MongoDB Schema Design: Part 1](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1), [Part 2](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87892923503/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2), [Part 3](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/88473035333/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3)
- [Data Models](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/data-modeling/)
- [Use Cases](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/)